# chrome.history is undefined in custom extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Below is my manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Print History",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["history", "tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action":{
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Below is my background js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});

});
```

Below is content js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
        alert("hello");
     chrome.history.getVisits({"url": "www.facebook.com"},
        function (visits) {
            if (visits.length >= 0) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, {
                    "message": "clicked_browser_action"
                });
            };
        });
    }
  }
);
```

The alert is printed on screen and I see an error in console saying undefined.getVisits. For some reason, chrome.history is undefined.
Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.history` can't be accessed in content scripts, you need to move that call to `background.js` and use something like [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to transfer data.

[Appendix](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> Content scripts can only access the following extension api:
>
> - extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )
> - i18n
> - runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
> - storage